# How can I create a Vue table component with column slots?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, html-table

I am currently working with a relatively large Vue (Vue 2) project that uses a lot of tables, and I want to create a reusable table component where each column is a child component / slot. Something like this:

```
<Table :data="data">
  <TableColumn field="id" label="ID" />
  <TableColumn field="name" label="Name" />
  <TableColumn field="date_created" label="Created" />
</Table>

const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Foo', date_created: '01.01.2021' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bar', date_created: '01.01.2021' }
];
```

Which in turn should output this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Created</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>01.01.2021</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>01.01.2021</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

We've previously used Buefy, but the vendor size becomes unnecessarily large, as we only use a fraction of the components' functionality - so I want to create a lightweight alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this data you only need 2 Props, labels and data.

```html
<!-- Component -->
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="(label, labelIndex) in labels" :key="labelIndex">
        {{ label.text }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item, itemIndex) in data" :key="itemIndex">
      <td v-for="(label, labelIndex) in labels" :key="labelIndex">
        {{ item[label.field] }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
// Data and labels
const labels = [
  { text: ID, field: id },
  { text: Name, field: name },
  { text: Created, field: date_created },
]
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Foo', date_created: '01.01.2021' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bar', date_created: '01.01.2021' }
];
```

```html
<table-component 
  :labels="labels" 
  :data="data"
>
</table-component>
```

If you need something more complex you can use nested components combined with a [named slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots) for the header or footer of the table (or other options like search).

Comment: That's an elegant way of solving it, thank you for the input!